# Mongodb aggregation framework performance

Tags: mongodb

I am using `mongodb` aggregation framework for all the get requests,when i say get request to fetch single document as well as multiple documents.For few requests i have around 90 to 100 stages in my aggregation pipeline(`$match`,`$skip`,`$limit`,`$lookup`,`$unwind`,`$addFields`,`$group`) these are stages what i am maintaining sequentially.If i pass limit more than 50 its giving error like `group stage has exceeded the memory limit` or else it taking around 60 seconds to execute the query.I my database each and every collection has more than 60,000 documents.How do i resolve this? Does sharding solves my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some optimizations for optimizing your query would be:
1. Try to reduce the number of records to be fetched at the first stage of the pipe line itself.
2. Create indexes on the fields being queried in the first pipeline, preferably a $match
3. Indexes will be used in the first stage of the pipeline only.
4. Sharding will increase throughput at the minor expense of query perf(this also depends)
Ps: lookup will not work on sharded connections

Comment: Also, to overcome memory exceed errors, try using allowdiskuse parameter in aggregation pipeline